# MongoMapper examine query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

How I can check which query will be send to the MongoDB server when I call a certain association on my model from the Rails console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turn on MongoMapper logging in your connection string (typically in an initializer file):

```
MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017, :logger => Rails.logger) #the logger param does the trick
```